# Google Maps JS slow on safari

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, safari

When using https://www.google.com/maps/ in Safari, zooming in is horribly slow using Windows or Mac. It feels glitchy as well; it starts to zoom then freezes then finishes. Chrome on both devices is fast.

Whether it's on Googles site or the JS api in mine, it's slow. OpenStreetMap.org is fast on Safari and Chrome.

This is also discussed on Apple forums and other threads. I haven't found any solutions to possibly enhance the JS api for my own web app.

Is Apple just trying to throw Google under the bus or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem with Safari. The only suggestion that I can give you is to go light mode (if that suits you).

Link: https://www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,4z?force=lite

Instruction link (enabling light mode):

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Change permanently UserAgent to Chrome and it should be OK:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari CustomUserAgent "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\""
```